# How to create a random walk in R that goes in different directions than -1 or +1?

Tags: r, sample, random-walk

Consider this  two‐dimensional random walk:

[image]

where, Zt, Wt, t = 1,2,3, … are independent and identically distributed standard normal
random variables.
I am having problems in finding a way to simulate and plot the sample path of (X,Y) for t = 0,1, … ,100. I was given a sample:

[image]

The following code is an example of  the way I am used to plot random walks in R:

```
set.seed(13579)
r<-sample(c(-1,1),size=100,replace=T,prob=c(0.5,0.5))
r<-c(10,r))
(w<-cumsum(r))
w<-as.ts(w)
plot(w,main="random walk")
```

I am not very sure of how to achieve this.
The problem I am having is that this kind of codes has a more "simple" result, with a line that goes either up or down, -1 or +1:
[image]

while the plot I need to create also goes from left to right and viceversa.

Would you help me in correcting the code I know so that it fits my task/suggesting a smarterst way to go about it? It would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `sample`, you need to use `rnorm(100)` to draw 100 samples from a standard normal distribution. Since the walk starts at [0, 0], we need to append a 0 at the start and do a `cumsum` on the result, i.e. `cumsum(c(0, rnorm(100)))`.

We want to do this for both the x and y variables, then plot. The whole thing can be done in a single line of code in base R:

```r
plot(x = cumsum(c(0, rnorm(100))), y = cumsum(c(0, rnorm(100))), type = 'l')
```

[image]